# How to change theMakefile for Fortran from Intel compiler with MKL to gfortran and Lapack/BLAS?

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, lapack, blas

I am new to Fortran and Makefile. I have received a code with a Makefile that uses the Intel compiler along with Lapack and BLAS as external libraries. I wish to make the Makefile with gfortran compiler.

I have installed `lapack` and `blas`.

```
libblas-dev is already the newest version (3.7.1-4ubuntu1).
libblas-dev set to manually installed.
liblapack-dev is already the newest version (3.7.1-4ubuntu1).
liblapack-dev set to manually installed.
```

But when I try to find them by which command, it shows nothing.

The snippet of the Makefile is as follows:

```
LIBS  = -L. -llapack -lblas
F90 = mpiifort

F90FLAGS  =  -traceback -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5
LIBS  =  -traceback -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5
```

I will be really helped to know, how can it be modified so that `gfortran` can be used along with Lapack and BLAS that are in my system.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] ans read [ask] and [mcve]. You should show more from your Makefile. There is probably much more to change. What exact `which` command did you try to find Lapack and BLAS? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: You have blas and lapack installed but the compiler does not know where to find them.  How to find them can be very system-dependent (though "which" is a good place to start) so I won't say anything about that.  Anyway, find their location and then replace "-L." with "-L<<location>>"